# Selecting Combinations Across Columns Row by Row With Overlap Threshold

Tags: r, dplyr, unique, combinations

I have a data frame that has rows that represent communities. For columns, the first column is the group that the community falls into (a total of 6 groups) and the remaining 8 are IDs of each member of the community.

What I would like to do is have a community (row) within groups 1, 3, and 5 to be picked where there is no overlap between them. Then, once I have that - I would like to pick a community from groups 2, 4, and 6 where there is no more than 25% overlap between the selected 6 total communities.

Here is an example dataset:

```
Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6)
Isol_1 = c(125, 25, 1, 126, 25, 128, 3, 128, 29, 15, 11, 18, 125, 6, 37, 4, 5, 19, 11, 4, 34, 32, 19, 1)
Isol_2 = c(8, 6, 56, 40, 37, 40, 125, 52, 4, 34, 25, 15, 15, 15, 23, 18, 63, 18, 22, 125, 23, 22, 11, 4)
Isol_3 = c(40, 34, 125, 63, 8, 25, 126, 48, 3, 125, 126, 37, 29, 126, 56, 29, 18, 40, 23, 25, 33, 43, 1, 11)
Isol_4 = c(127, 128, 8, 6, 38, 22, 25, 1, 63, 43, 22, 34, 4, 38, 22, 125, 48, 22, 126, 23, 32, 23, 23, 5)
Isol_5 = c(19, 4, 43, 125, 40, 37, 128, 125, 125, 23, 56, 43, 48, 48, 11, 33, 37, 63, 32, 63, 63, 48, 43, 52)
Isol_6 = c(33, 1, 128, 52, 124, 34, 15, 8, 40, 63, 4, 38, 5, 37, 8, 43, 32, 1, 19, 38, 22, 18, 56, 23)
Isol_7 = c(29, 63, 126, 128, 32, 63, 32, 11, 32, 33, 6, 6, 128, 19, 6, 15, 43, 33, 40, 11, 19, 56, 32, 18)
Isol_8 = c(3, 40, 34, 4, 56, 43, 52, 37, 38, 38, 52, 32, 11, 18, 33, 11, 1, 128, 37, 15, 56, 19, 5, 40)
df = cbind(Group, Isol_1, Isol_2, Isol_3, Isol_4, Isol_5, Isol_6, Isol_7, Isol_8)
```

Based on the criteria I mentioned above, the following could be pulled out:

Group 1: 125, 8, 40, 127, 19, 33, 29, 3

Group 3: 11, 25, 126, 22, 56, 4, 6, 52

Group 5: 5, 63, 18, 48, 37, 32, 43, 1

Group 2: 25, 37, 8, 38, 40, 124, 32, 56

Group 4: 125, 15, 29, 4, 48, 5, 128, 11

Group 6: 34, 23, 33, 32, 63, 22, 19, 56

Answer (score 3):

I believe this might be helpful (please let me know if not!).

The first step would be to subset your data into Group 1, 3, and 5. Then using `transpose` from `purrr`, splitting by `Group`, with `cross` we can get all combinations selecting one row from each group.

```
library(purrr)

grp_135 <- df[df$Group %in% c(1, 3, 5), ]
all_combn_135 <- lapply(cross(split(transpose(grp_135), grp_135$Group)), bind_rows)
```

Checking the first element to see what we have:

```
R> all_combn_135[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 9
  Group Isol_1 Isol_2 Isol_3 Isol_4 Isol_5 Isol_6 Isol_7 Isol_8
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1    125      8     40    127     19     33     29      3
2     3     29      4      3     63    125     40     32     38
3     5      5     63     18     48     37     32     43      1
```

Next, we can check for overlap by counting duplicates. In this case, I just `unlist` the three rows, use `table` for frequency, and sum up (subtracting 1 for each value found, since only want duplicates).

```
combn_ovlp_135 <- lapply(all_combn_135, function(x) {
  sum(table(unlist(x[-1])) - 1)
})
```

The ones without overlap can be obtained by:

```
no_ovlp <- all_combn_135[combn_ovlp_135 == 0]
no_ovlp

  Group Isol_1 Isol_2 Isol_3 Isol_4 Isol_5 Isol_6 Isol_7 Isol_8
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1    125      8     40    127     19     33     29      3
2     3     11     25    126     22     56      4      6     52
3     5      5     63     18     48     37     32     43      1
```

For the next part, do something similar (this can be broken out as a generalized function), except when checking for overlap, combine elements with the first `no_ovlp` from previously:

```
grp_246 <- df[df$Group %in% c(2, 4, 6), ]
all_combn_246 <- lapply(cross(split(transpose(grp_246), grp_246$Group)), bind_rows)

combn_ovlp_246 <- lapply(all_combn_246, function(x) {
  sum(table(c(unlist(x[-1]), unlist(no_ovlp[[1]][-1]))) - 1) / ((ncol(df) - 1) * 6)
})
```

It is not entirely clear how you want to calculate overlap for this part and compare with 25%. I counted duplicates and then divided by the number of columns (8 not counting `Group`) and multiply by 6 (rows). To see which combination of `Group` 2, 4, and 6 could be combined with `no_ovlp` you can try the following:

```
all_combn_246[combn_ovlp_246 < .25]
```

In my case, I believe none of the combinations met this criterion, although the first with 37.5% overlap was the minimum:

```
R> all_combn_246[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 9
  Group Isol_1 Isol_2 Isol_3 Isol_4 Isol_5 Isol_6 Isol_7 Isol_8
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     2     25     37      8     38     40    124     32     56
2     4    125     15     29      4     48      5    128     11
3     6     34     23     33     32     63     22     19     56
```

What was unclear is how to count duplicates. For example, how much overlap is  `c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3)`?

This could be two duplicates (two extra 3's):

```
R> sum(table(x) - 1)
[1] 2
```

Or you could count number of values that have any duplicates (just the number 3 is duplicated):

```
R> sum(table(x) > 1)
[1] 1
```

If it is the latter, you could try:

```
combn_ovlp_246 <- lapply(all_combn_246, function(x) {
  sum(table(c(unlist(x[-1]), unlist(no_ovlp[[1]][-1]))) > 1) / ((ncol(df) - 1) * 6)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By shamelessly stealing Ben's use of `cross()`, I have this approach that I personally find easier to read:

```
# Returns the number of overlapping elements
overlap <- function(xx){
  length(unlist(xx)) - length(unique(unlist(xx)))
}

df_135 <- df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  filter(Group %in% c(1,3,5)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Community = row_number()) %>%
  nest(Members = starts_with("Isol_")) %>%
  mutate(Members = map(Members, as.integer))

df_135
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   Group [3]
#   Group Community Members  
#   <dbl> <chr>     <list>   
# 1     1 g1_1      <int [8]>
# 2     1 g1_2      <int [8]>
# 3     1 g1_3      <int [8]>
# 4     1 g1_4      <int [8]>
# 5     3 g3_1      <int [8]>
# 6     3 g3_2      <int [8]>
# 7     3 g3_3      <int [8]>
# 8     3 g3_4      <int [8]>
# 9     5 g5_1      <int [8]>
#10     5 g5_2      <int [8]>
#11     5 g5_3      <int [8]>
#12     5 g5_4      <int [8]>

# Compute all combinations across groups
all_combns <- cross(split(df_135$Members, df_135$Group))

# select the combinations with the desired overlap
all_combns[map_int(all_combns, overlap) == 0]
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$`1`
# [1] 125   8  40 127  19  33  29   3
# 
# [[1]]$`3`
# [1]  11  25 126  22  56   4   6  52
# 
# [[1]]$`5`
# [1]  5 63 18 48 37 32 43  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plain R solution. It's not the most efficient one, but it's very straight forward and therefor very tractable.

The code below collects all the values in group 1 (1,3,5) and group 2 (2,4,6), and samples n isolates from this list. It then tests for the minimal overlap and resamples group 2 if necessary. In the case of your request, it only needs to resample once or twice, but if your threshold is lower (e.g. 0.05), it may resample up to 50 times before it gets it right. In fact, if your threshold is too low and your number of samples too large (i.e. it is impossible to make this sample), it will warn you that it failed.

```
Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6)
Isol_1 = c(125, 25, 1, 126, 25, 128, 3, 128, 29, 15, 11, 18, 125, 6, 37, 4, 5, 19, 11, 4, 34, 32, 19, 1)
Isol_2 = c(8, 6, 56, 40, 37, 40, 125, 52, 4, 34, 25, 15, 15, 15, 23, 18, 63, 18, 22, 125, 23, 22, 11, 4)
Isol_3 = c(40, 34, 125, 63, 8, 25, 126, 48, 3, 125, 126, 37, 29, 126, 56, 29, 18, 40, 23, 25, 33, 43, 1, 11)
Isol_4 = c(127, 128, 8, 6, 38, 22, 25, 1, 63, 43, 22, 34, 4, 38, 22, 125, 48, 22, 126, 23, 32, 23, 23, 5)
Isol_5 = c(19, 4, 43, 125, 40, 37, 128, 125, 125, 23, 56, 43, 48, 48, 11, 33, 37, 63, 32, 63, 63, 48, 43, 52)
Isol_6 = c(33, 1, 128, 52, 124, 34, 15, 8, 40, 63, 4, 38, 5, 37, 8, 43, 32, 1, 19, 38, 22, 18, 56, 23)
Isol_7 = c(29, 63, 126, 128, 32, 63, 32, 11, 32, 33, 6, 6, 128, 19, 6, 15, 43, 33, 40, 11, 19, 56, 32, 18)
Isol_8 = c(3, 40, 34, 4, 56, 43, 52, 37, 38, 38, 52, 32, 11, 18, 33, 11, 1, 128, 37, 15, 56, 19, 5, 40)
df = cbind(Group, Isol_1, Isol_2, Isol_3, Isol_4, Isol_5, Isol_6, Isol_7, Isol_8)

df = as.data.frame(df)
subset1 <- df[df$Group %in% c(1,3,5),]
subset2 <- df[df$Group %in% c(2,4,6),]

values_in_subset1 <- subset1[2:ncol(subset1)]        # Drop group column
values_in_subset1 <- as.vector(t(values_in_subset1)) # Convert to single vector

values_in_subset2 <- subset2[2:ncol(subset2)]        # Drop group column
values_in_subset2 <- as.vector(t(values_in_subset2)) # Convert to single vector

n_sampled <- 8

sample1 <- sample(values_in_subset1, n_sampled, replace=F)  #Replace=F is default, added here for readability
sample2 <- sample(values_in_subset2, n_sampled, replace=F)  #Replace=F is default, added here for readability
percentage_overlap <- sum(sample1 %in% sample2)/n_sampled

min_percentage_overlap <- 0.25
retries <- 1

# Retry until it gets it right
while(percentage_overlap > min_percentage_overlap && retries < 1000)
{
    retries <- retries + 1
    sample2 <- sample(values_in_subset2, n_sampled, replace=F)  #Replace=F is default, added here for readability
    percentage_overlap <- sum(sample1 %in% sample2)/n_sampled
}

# Report on number of attempts
cat(paste("Sampled", retries, "times to make sure there was less than", min_percentage_overlap*100,"% overlap."))

# Finally, check if it worked.
if(percentage_overlap <= min_percentage_overlap){ 
        cat("It's super effective! (not really though)")
} else {
    cat("But it failed!")
}
```